# General Formula for Defined Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

While solving a programming challenge, I've had to efficiently evaluate the following function:

Given $n$ and $b$, return the number of natural numbers within the interval $[1, n]$ where bit index $b$ is set.

In set builder notation:

$$
|\{x | x \in \mathbb{N} \land 1 \leq x \leq n \land \operatorname{bit_set}(x, b)\}|
$$

For example, to compute the function at $n = 6, b = 2$:

```
1 => 0b001 & 0b100 => 0b000 > 0 => false
2 => 0b010 & 0b100 => 0b000 > 0 => false
3 => 0b011 & 0b100 => 0b000 > 0 => false
4 => 0b100 & 0b100 => 0b000 > 0 => false
5 => 0b101 & 0b100 => 0b100 > 0 => true
6 => 0b110 & 0b100 => 0b100 > 0 => true

2 true values. f(6, 2) = 2
```

I am searching for an efficient-to-compute form of this function. The method displayed above is very slow for large n.

The function clearly obeys some patterns. Here is a graph of some small values:
[image: Display of values]

As is visible on the graph, each value of $b$ produces a staircase pattern. The number of points in the slants and flat parts of the shape are always the same.

Here is a link to a plotly with the data below. That also contains the raw term values. [https://plotly.com/~carsonriker/1/](https://plotly.com/%7Ecarsonriker/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot shows the key: starting from $0$ the $b$-th bit is $0$ for $2^b$ values, then $1$ for the next $2^b$, then repeating. Thus
$$f(n)=2^b\lfloor(n+1)/2^{b+1}\rfloor+f(r=(n+1)\bmod2^{b+1})$$
and the latter is easily seen to be $\min(0,r-(2^b-1))$.

The first term can easily be implemented by shifting, and the second is as easily evaluated by looking at the $2^b$ bit of $n+1$ and returning that bit multiplied by the bits to the right.